# Scraping Reviews from TripAdvisor Selenium Error HTML element

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am trying to scrape reviews from TripAdvisor using Selenium Python. This is my code:

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import csv
conda install -c conda-forge selenium

import csv #This package lets us save data to a csv file
from selenium import webdriver #The Selenium package we'll need
import time #This package lets us pause execution for a bit
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

path_to_file = "/Users/avdv/Desktop/HotelReviews6.csv"
pages_to_scrape = 3
url = "https://www.tripadvisor.nl/Restaurant_Review-g188590-d12090410-Reviews-Wijmpje_Beukers-Amsterdam_North_Holland_Province.html"

driver = webdriver.Safari()
driver.get(url)

csvFile = open(path_to_file, 'a', encoding="utf-8")
csvWriter = csv.writer(csvFile)

for i in range(0, pages_to_scrape):

```
time.sleep(2)
    
time.sleep(2)
driver.find_element(By.XPATH,".//span[contains(@class,'taLnk ulBlueLinks')]").click()

container = driver.find_elements("xpath","//div[@data-reviewid]")


for j in range(len(container)): # A loop defined by the number of reviews

    title = container[j].find_element("xpath",".//span[@class='noQuotes']").text
    date = container[j].find_element("xpath",".//span[contains(@class, 'ratingDate')]").get_attribute("title")
    rating = container[j].find_element("xpath",".//span[contains(@class, 'ui_bubble_rating bubble_')]").get_attribute("class").split("_")[3]
    review = container[j].find_element("xpath",".//p[@class='partial_entry']").text.replace("\n", " ")
    
    csvWriter.writerow([date, rating, title, review]) 

driver.find_element("xpath",".//a[@class='nav next ui_button primary']").click()
```

driver.quit()

I keep on getting a "WebdriverException" error with the following details:
---> 27     driver.find_element("xpath",".//a[@class='nav next ui_button primary']").click()

How can I solve this?